# How should I understand $f^{-1}(E):=\{x\in A:f(x)\in E\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, inverse

I understand the concept, but I still can't figure out how to read the notation:

$$f^{-1}(E):=\{x\in A:f(x)\in E\}$$

I understood the concept due to the examples, not with the notation. Can someone *translate*/explain how to read it to me?

I'm thinking that it means: *All numbers that when evaluated, will result in $f(x)$*, I could find a inverse image in $f(x)=x^2+x$, for example: Consider $A=\{2,-3\}$ and $B=\{6\}$ where $A$ is the inverse image, for this I just took the procedure I found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image).

> For example, for the function $f(x) = x^2$, the inverse image of $\{4\}$ would be $\{-2,2\}$.

But I got confused when I read this:

> [$x^2+x$  is not invertible as a function on R. Are you restricting the domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199377/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-x2x#comment455962_199377)

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $f^{-1}(E)$???

Comment: Oh, no. It's because I omited some details which are contained in the [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360722/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-inverse-image). Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that in modern mathematics functions are also relations, i.e. sets of ordered pairs. Given a relation $R$, we can talk about the inverse relation, $R^{-1}=\{\langle y,x\rangle\mid \langle x,y\rangle\in R\}$.

To understand the inverse relation one simply has to think about a relation as a bunch of arrows between points, and the inverse relation is merely the inversion of these arrows.

Now it should be simpler to understand $f^{-1}(E)$. This is the inverse relation of $f$. Note that if $f$ is injective, then $f^{-1}(x)$ is at most one point, and that defines a function (on a subset of the codomain); but this is irrelevant to the main point: "**$f^{-1}(E)$ is the image of $E$ under the inverse relation of $f$**"

---

On a general level, when we write $\{x\mid \varphi(x)\}$ (the $\mid$ is sometimes replaced by $\colon$) we define a collection, naively a set, which includes *all* the objects $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is true for them.

When we write $\{x\in A\mid\varphi(x)\}$ we mean $\{x\mid x\in A\land\varphi(x)\}$. This way we limit our collection to elements of $A$. This is a solution for several possible paradoxes of naive set theory when we assume that $A$ is a set, and the result is a set.

Comment: I loved your notation, it's way more comprehensible. But what confused me is the meaning of: $\{x\in A:f(x)\in E\}$ what did he meant with that?

Comment: Gustavo, this is simply the "direct image of the inverse relation". It is all the points in the domain of $f$ which are mapped into $E$.

Comment: Yes. But I'm trying to figure out as if it were a programming languange, if I were to read $\{(\text{message 1}):\text{(message 2)}\}$ how would it be? Is it something like: "All the $x$'s that make the given $f(x)$'s?

Comment: In which programming language? In Common Lisp it would simply be defining message 2 as a predicate, and considering those in $A$ which satisfy it. Your question doesn't make much sense to me, because mathematics is **not** a programming language.

Comment: I didn't say mathematics is a programming languange. I said that set theory seems to be.

Comment: I've made [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/281568/25805) some time ago, look: *Logically speaking set theory is perfectly adequate since all of homological algebra can be stated in ZFC. But, just like some programming languages are better suited for certain tasks then others (but ultimately they are all equivalent to machine code) so is it in mathematics that the choice of base language may be suited to certain things more than to others.*

Comment: Set theory is probably the least "programming language" part of mathematics I know. The fact that someone used **an analogy** does not even remotely begins to justify this sort of reasoning too. Do you know how many analogies between mathematics and other things I make every day? I don't see how diagrams (in the sense of category theory) are anything like cauliflower.

Comment: I got this idea of category theory and set theory as something similar to programming languanges - but the similarity rests only in the power to describe some mathematical idea, I guess.

Comment: You got the idea wrong. These are languages and they are used to express certain things. Yes, there is a similarity to programming language -- both things are **languages**. But that's roughly where the analogy ends.

Comment: Yes. I guess I could only accept ST as a tool for describing something. I can't make a program with it, in this sense, I guess the nearest thing to a programming languange would be logic.

Comment: Also, to push *your* idea further, try reading a block of code in Bovine, or in Brainfuck. Then try reading the same block of code in Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure, C++, Visual Basic, Delphi, and lastly x86 assembler. Your ability to parse the same block of code depends on your ability to understand the language. Your question, if so, should not be "how to parse this block of code, which I already fully understand through examples" but "how do I understand the language of set theory?".

Comment: Logic is also not very close to a programming language. You should probably forget this sort of analogy altogether.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. Sorry, english is not my native languange neither am I proeficient at it - organizing what I want to communicate sometimes fails. I've read some elementary stuff on ST, but it's the first time I see such argument: $\{x\in A:f(x)\in E\}$. I mean, I understand the concept now, but If I see a similar argument in the future, I'll not be able to understand (through the argument), perhaps only through the examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a function $f:A \to B$, you can always define a **set-valued** inverse $f^{-1}(E)$ as above, ie, all elements of $A$ that map into the set $E \subset B$.

It may be empty, as in $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^2$, then $f^{-1} [-2,-1] = \emptyset$.

It may have many values as in $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 1$, then $f^{-1} \{1\} = \mathbb{R}$.

It may be a singleton as in $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^3$, then $f^{-1} \{y\} = \{ \sqrt[3]{y} \}$.

Note that $f^{-1}(E) \subset A$ is a set.

However, if it turns out that $f^{-1} \{ y \}$ is a singleton for all $y \in B$, then you can define an inverse function, which (confusingly) is also denoted by the same symbol. In this case we have (the function) $f^{-1}(y) = x$, where $x \in f^{-1}\{y\}$ (this $f^{-1}$ is the set-valued inverse, remember that we are presuming that it is a singleton here).

Comment: Isn't it the set $E\subseteq B$? In the book it's stated in this form. Earlier in the book, the author mentions about *defining a function "in pieces"*. I guess it's related somehow.

Comment: @Gustavo: Yes, it is, but $f^{-1}(B)=A$ almost by definition, so it doesn't make much difference if you consider $E=B$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition is also called the preimage/pre-image of $E$: the subset of the domain $A$ that gets mapped to $E$. Draw a Venn-type diagram, a region for $A$, and an arrow from $A$ to a set $B$, the image of $A$ inside the range. Now imagine that $E$ is a set that has nonempty intersection with $B$. Which elements of $A$ get mapped into $E$ (or, more precisely, into its intersection with $B$)? You can refine your diagram by splitting $A$ into a part that gets mapped under $f$ into $E$, and another part that gets mapped into the rest of $B$. The former part is the pre-image of $E$ in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Take for example $f:R \rightarrow [-1,1]$ as $f(x)= sin(\pi x)$ let $E= \{1\}$ then $f^{-1}(E)=\{x\in R:f(x)\in E\}= \{\pm \frac{1}{2}, \pm \frac{5}{2}, \pm \frac{9}{2},..\}$ Because $f(\pm \frac{1}{2})=1 \in E$, $f(\pm \frac{5}{2})=1 \in E$,  and so forth.

but we cannot define a function $g:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ to be  $f^{-1}$ on the entire domain of $f$ because then $g$ is not well-defined i.e $g(1)$ has infinitely many values, So you need to restrict $f$ on some interval like for example $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ instead of $\mathbb R$ in this case $g(y)$ has only one image in $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$, $\forall y \in [-1,1] $.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of a point is a set. So you can not define one well defined point as the inverse image. Hence its not a function. such as $f^{-1}(6)=\{2,-3\}$ So which one you define as the inverse image ?

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict the domain $A$ to be $[0,\infty)$, for example, then the function $f$ is invertible, because for each value $f(x)$, there exists a unique $x$ in the (now restricted) domain $[0,\infty)$ that generates that value.

Therefore, the function $f(x)=x^2+x$ is not invertible **as a function on $\mathbb R$**, because $\mathbb R$ also includes negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Emended picture from http://yorkporc.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/transforms-pre-images-and-kernels-and-null-spaces/

[image]

The original picture from Khan Academy has still more colours which I've lessened.

The pink should avail to answer your question:
It's the preimage/inverse image of $S \subseteq Y$ (though this picture shows $S \subsetneq Y$) under $T$ $= T^{-1}[S] = \{x \in X : T(x) \in S\}$.